# Is there a way to check which topic a word would be in?

Tags: python, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

I have used Gensim's LDA topic modeling to create 6 topics. But now I would like to give the model a word and see which topic that would fall under. Is this possible? If so through which method?

**Ex.**
Enter word('Fitness') => LDA Model => Percentage of which topic the word would best fit under (if in the dictionary)

Something like:

```
Topic 1: 2%,
Topic 2: 5%, 
Topic 3: 1%,
Topic 4: 89%,
Topic 5: 1%,
Topic 6: 2%
```

Thus, I could say this word fits best under topic 4.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Gensim's LDA implementation includes the method `get_term_topics(word_id, minimum_probability=None)`:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html#gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel.get_term_topics

It returns topics, & relative probabilities, for the given word *by its integer ID within the model) - optional clipped to some optional `minimum_probability`. (I'm not certain if the probabilities are guaranteed to sum to `1.0` - check that & consider scaling its results if you need to.)